# Use uWebSockets with my own httpServer implementation

Tags: node.js, sockets, uwebsockets

I have a NodeJs application and I want to use uWebSockets.
The problem is that I have a predefined custom HTTP server that I must use.
I wanted to know if its possible to inject our custom HTTP server to uWebSockets

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seems that uWebSockets supports the HTTP object of NodeJS

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).